# Why is the integral of $\int_0^\pi \sin x$ equivalent to two and not half the area of a unit circle?

Tags: calculus, geometry, definite-integrals

The integral: $\int_0^\pi \sin x=2$ however there is something I am missing which is that the area of half a unit circle is equivalent to $\pi/2$. This same logic applies to the $\cos x$ function but shouldn't taking each individual rectangle from the height $sinx$ function be equivalent to the half the total area? I think it is because of the correspondence between the change in $dx$ and $d\theta$ since $d\theta$ is greater for every change $dx$. Wouldn't these differences be negligible as you evaluate the limit of $dx$?

Comment: The area of half a unit circle is $\pi^2/2$.

Comment: @MartinR Shouldn't it be $\pi r^2/2$?

Comment: OK, but why should $\int_0^\pi \sin(x) \, dx$ have the same value?

Comment: Because of the correspondence of the Riemann sum of each individual height length summed up from 0 to $\pi$ right?

Comment: If $y = \sin x$ between $\left[0, \pi \right]$ corresponded to a semi-circle, then the distance between centre $(\frac{\pi}{2}, 0)$ and each point on the curve would be $1$. But it is not - consider the point $(\frac{\pi}{6}, \frac{1}{2})$ for example. And it is pretty obvious from the shape of the curve that that section of the graph does not correspond to half a unit circle as well. Also this: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bnqjyjcnjv

Comment: Have you tried plotting the function $\sin(x)$ and observing if the area under the curve resembles a circle?

Comment: The $\sin(x)$ function corresponds to the height for a given angle $x$, not a $x$-coordinate. You would be assuming some kind of linear correspondence between the angle and the $x$-coordinate which is not true.

Comment: @PhysicsMathLove Oh yeah that makes sense so it's based off the correspondence between the radius and the $sinx$ function alright thanks to everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unit circle is the set of points $(x, y)\in\mathbb R^2$ that satisfy
$$
x^2+y^2\le 1, $$
so the area of its upper portion is given by the integral 
$$
\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}\, dx.$$
The change of variable $x=\cos t$ gives 
$$
\int_0^\pi \sin^2 t\, dt, $$ 
so it is this last integral that is related to the circle, not $\int_0^\pi \sin t\, dt$.

Comment: you beat my by 30 secs.

Comment: @Thomas: sorry, sometimes this website encourages the "fastest gun in the West"-style of answering.

Comment: That makes sense it also explains something which was also messing with me which is the negative area from $\pi$ to $2\pi$ of the function $sinx$. Thanks!